# How to check support compile flag in autoconf for clang

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang++, autoconf

We can check support for specific compiler flags in `autoconf` using:

```
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(FLAG, [ACTION-SUCCESS], [ACTION-FAILURE], [EXTRA-FLAGS], [INPUT])
```

These checks are returning true but `clang` doesn't support them.

```
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Woverride-init])
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Wformat-truncation])
```

How to check support compile flag in `autoconf` for `clang`?

I change my compiler by

```
export CC=/usr/bin/clang-6.0 
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++-6.0
```

and if echo into script `$CC` and `$CXX`, all is ok.

[link to configure.ac](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/blob/master/configure.ac#L310)

Comment: Check/select your compiler first. The flag checks should then use `Clang` if that’s the elected compiler.

Comment: it was already checked  clang-6.0 and clang++-6.0

Comment: Try `./configure CC="$CC" CXX="$CXX"`.

Comment: You should be able to put together a minimal example (an MCVE — [MCVE]).  I suspect there'd be about 6 lines of `autoconf` code to show (start, end, compiler check, plus the `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` lines, and maybe I've forgotten something), plus the command line you run, plus the trace output you get.

Comment: ./configure CC="$CC" CXX="$CXX" this tip doesn't  help. @jonathan-leffler I add link to source configure file with anchor to nonworking command.

Comment: 3300 lines of `configure.ac` is not an MCVE.  I spent a few minutes trying to strip it down, but it seems to rely on some extra bits and pieces that I don't have in my AutoTools setup (the `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` macro is one).  You've not shown the start of the output from running the configure script.  When I run `sh configure.sh CC=/usr/bin/clang CXX=/usr/bin/clang++` with a `configure.sh` created from a cut-down `configure.ac`, I get lines like: `checking for gcc... /usr/bin/clang` and `checking whether /usr/bin/clang++ accepts -g... yes`.  Are you seeing equivalent lines in your output?

Answer (score 8):

If you use `clang -Wsome-invalid-option -xc /dev/null`, you'll see that clang emits a warning about an unknown option `-Wsome-invalid-option`.  The docs for `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` state that warnings are ignored.

You need to use argument 4 of the macro to include `-Werror`:

```
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Woverride-init], , , [-Werror])
```

This check also generates a cache variable, in case you need to override it:

```
ax_cv_cflags__Werror__Woverride_init
```

If it's set to `yes`, then the compiler supports the flag, else it does not support the flag.  You can use this for other flags as well:

```
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Wformat-truncation], , , [-Werror])
AS_VAR_IF([ax_cv_cflags__Werror__Wformat_truncation], [yes],
    ,
    [AC_FATAL([-Wformat-truncation not supported])])
```

The generic form is `ax_cv_cflags_{EXTRA}_{FLAG}` for C.  Obviously if you're going to use `AS_VAR_IF` to check the cache variable, however, you may as well use the second and/or third macro arguments as well, and you can use `AC_FATAL` if the compilation flag is required:

```
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Wformat-truncation],
    ,
    [AC_FATAL([-Wformat-truncation is required])],
    [-Werror])
```